# can i use setLocation for JButton on an image?

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jbutton

I'm trying to put a button on top of an image, but it's not working.

```
GridLayout frame = new GridLayout();
setLayout (frame);

panelOne.add(background);
btn.setLocation (200, 200);
panelOne.add(btn);
add(panelOne);
```

Comment: Essentially, my image is a background, and I want to put a JButton on top of it.

Comment: First and foremost -- learn how the layout managers work, because you're very confused about GridLayout and how it works. Next, if you are still confused on how to fix your problem, then next, learn how to create and post a decent [mcve].

Comment: [Further reading](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+swing+put+button+on+top+of+image)